# Jquery Ajax call to url not working in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax

I use ajax call in my aspx page and also use URL Rewrite. Ajax call hit the webMethod without URL Rewrite rule but after applying Rewrite Rule it stop working.

My aspx page ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../cc/page.aspx/SendNewsletter",
        data: d,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert('hi');
            if (response.d == "1") {
                alert("Newsletter has been sent successfully.");

            }
            else {
                alert("Something went wrong.Please try again later.");
            }
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    }).always(function () {

    });
```

And my Webmethod is:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SendNewsletter(string to, string newsletter, string newslettername)
{
}
```

My Rewrite Rule is:

```
<rule name="Rewrite normal CC request to aspx">
                <match url="^cc/(.*)$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="cc/{R:1}.aspx" />
            </rule>
```

Comment: Ajax calls automatically cache, so first call will hit the webmethod and subsequent calls on the same page will not.  YOu can add `cache: false,`.  Is that the issue?

Comment: @Gray Holland thanx for reply. I have used it already but didn't find it working. Problem is my code is not able to hit the url ../cc/page.aspx/SendNewsletter

Comment: Can you set the WebMethod as ScriptMethod as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your urlrewriterule is turning your original url `/cc/page.aspx/SendNewsletter` into `/cc/page.aspx/SendNewsletter.aspx`

Change the rule to the following

```
<rule name="Rewrite normal CC request to aspx" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^cc/([^/]*)/(.*)$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="cc/{R:1}.aspx/{R:2}" />
</rule>
<rule name="Rewrite normal CC" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^cc/([^?]*)?(.*)$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="cc/{R:1}.aspx?{R:2}" />
</rule>
```

And change your url to `../cc/page/SendNewsletter`

Comment: Thanx for reply @Arperum. This rule stop my other pages such as http://example.com/cc/page?q=...

Comment: When I use both rules, my main url http://example.com/cc/page?q=123 start working but ajax call still not working.

Comment: I update the rule a bit, what url do you call in your ajax call? did you change that to point to cc/page/sendnewsletter? Or does the ajax call still contain the .aspx in the url?

Comment: I used updated rules, normal links work fine now but ajax call is still not working. I have used ../cc/page/SendNewsletter in ajax url.

Comment: I updated the post with the stopProcessing attribute added to the rewrite rules, does that fix the issue?

Comment: Thanx a lot @Arperum.. stopProcessing  attribute worked for me.